# What is the best way to handle several timers in the same class?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I'm using several timers in my class, and wondering about two options to implement it:

**Option 1 :**

Each message has its own Timer.

```
 class MessagesManager1
{
    Timer _timerA = new Timer();
    Timer _timerB = new Timer();
    Timer _timerC = new Timer();

    public MessagesManager1()
    {
        _timerA.Interval = 1000; // 1 sec
        _timerB.Interval = 3000; // 3 sec
        _timerC.Interval = 5000; // 5 sec

        _timerA.Elapsed += _timerA_Elapsed;
        _timerB.Elapsed += _timerB_Elapsed;
        _timerC.Elapsed += _timerC_Elapsed;

        _timerA.Start();
        _timerB.Start();
        _timerC.Start();
    }

    void _timerA_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // send message A
    }

    void _timerB_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // send message B
    }

    void _timerC_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // send message C
    }
}
```

**Option 2 :**
Use only one timer and send each message depends on the secondsCounter modulus result.

```
 class MessagesManager2
{
    Timer _timer = new Timer();

    public MessagesManager2()
    {
        _timer.Interval = 1000; // 1 sec

        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    int secondsCounter;

    void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // send message A

        if (secondsCounter % 3 == 0)
        {
            // send message B
        }

        if (secondsCounter % 5 == 0)
        {
            // send message C
        }
    }
}
```

Which one is better and why?
(in terms of performance,architecture,maintenance,best practices...etc).

Comment: Option 1 for maintainability reasons, but really it's up to you since you'll be dealing with it.

Comment: Can you provide more details (e.g an upper bound on the expected number of timers you will have)? In general, the easier to read or understand case is better, so probably your first option.

Comment: There is insufficient context to provide a good answer. Your second option is overkill; option #1 will work fine. But that's about all that can be said about it. Your request for a discussion of "why?" makes the question too broad anyway, but there's not enough detail here to really address that in any case.

Comment: Maybe not enough information for constructive answers with regards Performance, but there is plenty to go on with regards architecture, maintenance and best practices.

Answer (score 0):

I would say none of those.

You should follow the Single Responsibility Principle - in both of your options, the same class is carrying out more than one thing.

I would create a class that has a single Timer, and then create 3 instances of that class at runtime, passing the interval value into the constructor.

Depending on what needs to be done in the Elapsed event, you could either pass an `Action` delegate into the constructor, or instead create derived classes that override an abstract/virtual method with the required behaviour.

**Approach 1**

If you know you are only ever going to have these three things to handle, then I would say its best to define them as explicit behaviours at compile time:

```
public abstract class BaseTimerHandler
{
    private readonly Timer m_Timer;

    public BaseTimerHandler(int interval)
    {
        m_Timer = new Timer();
        m_Timer.Interval = interval;
        m_Timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
        m_Timer.Start();
    }

    protected abstract TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e);

    //TODO unsubscribe from Elapsed in Dispose method.
}

public class TimerAHandler : BaseTimerHandler
{
    private const int _INTERVAL = 1000;
    public TimerAHandler() : base(_INTERVAL) { }

    protected override TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //send message A
    }
}

public class TimerBHandler : BaseTimerHandler
{
    private const int _INTERVAL = 3000;
    public TimerBHandler() : base(_INTERVAL) { }

    protected override TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //send message B
    }
}

public class TimerCHandler : BaseTimerHandler
{
    private const int _INTERVAL = 5000;
    public TimerCHandler() : base(_INTERVAL) { }

    protected override TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //send message C
    }
}
```

**Approach 2**

If you are talking about having a variable number of these timers, perhaps defined at runtime, then I would inject the behaviour instead of defining explicit classes (adjust the `Action` delegate to include parameters if you need the sender or event args).

```
public class TimerHandler
{
    private readonly Timer m_Timer;
    private readonly Action m_Elapsed;

    public BaseTimerHandler(int interval, Action sendMessage)
    {
        if (sendMessage == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sendMessage", "Must provide send message");

        m_Timer = new Timer();
        m_Timer.Interval = interval;
        m_Timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;

        m_Elapsed = sendMessage;

        m_Timer.Start();
    }

    private TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e){
    {
        m_Elapsed();
    }

    //TODO unsubscribe from Elapsed in Dispose method.
}

var timerA = new TimerHandler(1, () => { //send message A });
var timerB = new TimerHandler(3, () => { //send message B });
var timerC = new TimerHandler(5, () => { //send message B });
```

This might seem a little like overkill, but I am assuming your example is simplified. In both cases the advantages are:

- You can unit test the timer handling separately from the actual code to be executed in the Elapsed (in the BaseTimerHandler you can create a Mock derived type for Unit Test, in the TimerHandler you can inject a fake `Action`).
- You have removed duplication of the timer code, so more maintainable and ensures consistency.
- If the code to be executed in the Elapsed also contains some common code, then you can expand the BaseTimerHandler.TimerElapsed to be a virtual method and add this common code, or for the TimerHandler, expand the TimerElapsed to contain the common code.